# Remove capital letters from end of string

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of strings that look like:

`var uglystrings = ["ChipBagYAHSC","BlueToothNSJ"]`

They all have a 2-5 capital letters at the end. I would like to remove the capital letters from the end using js but I am not sure what is the most efficient way? I cannot do `substr` because they all will have a different number of capital letters at the end

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Iterate the array using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the uppercase letters of at the end of each string using a RegExp ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8FAdAh/1)):

```js
var uglystrings = ["ChipBagYAHSC","BlueToothNSJ"];

var result = uglystrings.map(function(str) {
  return str.replace(/[A-Z]+$/, '');
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: ES6 version: `uglystrings.map(str => str.replace(/[A-Z]+$/, ‘’));`